# Puppeteer - test that file would have been downloaded without downloading the whole file

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

I am using [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) with [jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest), and have a test that clicks a `<button>`, which downloads a file.

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', { behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: './' })
await page.click('.download-button');
```

I can see that the Chrome actually downloads the whole file, which is large.

How can I test that the file would have been downloaded, but not actually download the file?

It would also be acceptable to only download a small portion of the file before aborting, as long as I can test that the download started.

Comment: Mock out the actual download of the file, to simply return to you a small, static response and then continue.

Comment: How do I mock out the actual download of the file?

Comment: Page.setDownloadBehavior is deprecated and can be removed, I recommend you to use a http request or something like that. You can see it on https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-setDownloadBehavior

Comment: I want to test that clicking a specific button downloads a file. How do I use an http request in this scenario?

Comment: The mock does not download the file, it simply replaces the calls, so that you simulate the call, but do not actually reach out and download the file.  The mock simply can return success, and a small, constant file for your processing.  Best to see the actual tool you use for how to do it, as they have many examples.  https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions

Comment: It may not have been clear, but I don't want to mock internals of the libraries which handle the button click, I'd rather be generic and mock all file downloads in the browser. I'd like to treat the code as a black box. I don't have control over the server which serves the download file either either